# Network error from google services in Android

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I am developing an app in which i have an integrated google drive. I want to store images captured by the device under a folder in google drive. 
By doing so in result.getstatus() method from google service is returning **{statusCode=Failed to retrieve item from a network}**

I am using following function,

```
 final ResultCallback<DriveIdResult> idCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveIdResult>() {

    @Override

    public void onResult(DriveIdResult result) {


          System.out.println("result.getStatus()----"+ result.getStatus());

          System.out.println("result.getStatus() code----"+   result.getStatus().getStatusCode());



        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {

            showMessage("Cannot find DriveId. Are you authorized to view this file?");

            return;

        }

        DriveFolder folder = Drive.DriveApi

                .getFolder(getGoogleApiClient(), result.getDriveId());

        MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()

                .setTitle("NewFolder").build();

        folder.createFolder(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet)

                .setResultCallback(createFolderCallback);

    }

};
```

In first println---> I am getting **{statusCode=Failed to retrieve item from a network}**

In second println--> I am getting 7

Please help me...

Comment: what error you are getting???

Comment: @rajshree i am getting {statusCode=Failed to retrieve item from a network}

Comment: try to debug your code..,and check all values..

Comment: @rajshree i have debugged but can't able to spot the error

Comment: What call are you making that results in that callback?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same status code when the file is permanently deleted. Remove any cached DriveId / resource id and create the new file.